# Is every retraction a bounded map?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $r: X \to P$ be a retraction, i.e., continuous and $r(x)=x$ for all $x\in P$.
Here, $X$ is a Banach space and $P$ is a closed convex subset of $X$ or more specifically $P$ is a positive cone.

(1) I was wondering if $r$ is a bounded map, i.e., for a bounded subset $A$, $r(A)$ is bounded.

The above question is related to the following result:

(2) If $T: P \to P$ is a continuous and compact operator, i.e., for a bounded subset $A$, $T(A)$ is relatively compact, then $T\circ r$ is a compact operator.

Actually, I’d like to prove $(2)$. If $(1)$ is true, then $(2)$ follows. $(1)$ may not be true generally.

Please let me know if you have any idea or comment for this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $r$ assumed to be continuous at all?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Yes it is.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  also, $r(x)=x$ for $x\in P$

Comment: Yes if $X$ is finite-dimensional. If $A$ is bounded, then its closure is compact, hence $r(A)$ is contained in a compact set.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for your comment. How about the infinite dimensional Banach space?

Comment: That is the difficult part ... if $P$ is bounded, then it is true again.

Comment: @PaulFrost If (1) is not true in general, how about (2)? Here, T is continuous and compact.

Comment: Is $X$ reflexive or not? It's separable?

Comment: @P De Donato No, it is just a real Banach space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately both are false, at least in an infinite dimensional case.

For (1) let $X=l^\infty$ be the Banach space of all real bounded sequences with $sup$ norm.

Consider $e_i=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ with $1$ on $i$-th position. Note that $\lVert e_i-e_j\lVert=1$ for $i\neq j$ and $\lVert e_i\rVert=1$. Furthermore let $P=\{(r,0,0,\ldots)\ |\ r\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Now let $A=P\cup\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and note that $A$ is closed in $X$. Consider the function

$$f:A\to P$$
$$f(v)=\begin{cases}
v &\text{if }v\in P \\
(i,0,0,\ldots) &\text{if }v=e_i
\end{cases}$$

Note that $f$ is continuous because $A$ is (topologically) a disjoint union of $P, \{e_1\}, \{e_2\},\ldots$ By [the Tietze Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) $f$ can be extended to $r:X\to P$ which is a retraction by the construction.

However $r(\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty)=f(\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty)$ is not bounded even though $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is.

This example can be used in (2) to show that $(T\circ r)(\{e_i\})$ is unbounded and thus not relatively compact, e.g. take $T:P\to P$ to be the identity (note that the identity is a compact operator on finite dimensional spaces).

So assumptions about $T$ and $r$ being linear are essential here as noted by @Paul Frost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will think over your answer. Is it $i \ge2$?

Comment: @0706 You mean in the definition of $A$? Yeah, it doesn't matter, $e_1\in P$ anyway.

Comment: You are right. But the identity is not compact on infinite dimensional space. For finite dimensional space, $(1)$ is true as the above comment.

Comment: @0706 In my counterexample $P$ is finite dimensional, not $X$. You are referring to the case when $X$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Okay. I have one more question. What is Tietze extension theorem? Is it for real valued function?

Comment: @0706 Classical result in topology that says that every continuous function defined on a closed subspace can be extended to whole space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem Yes, it is for real valued functions, but here $P$ is pretty much $\mathbb{R}$. Formally we would define $f$ to have values in $\mathbb{R}$ and then compose $f$ with embedding $i:\mathbb{R}\to P$ but this is are just technical details.

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is a closed convex set in a normed space, you are right. But $A$ is not convex.

Comment: @0706 $A$ need not be convex or even connected (it is not in my example). It is a general theorem concering general topological spaces. The concept of being convex doesn't even make sense there. The **only** assumption is that it is closed. Please read the wiki article I've posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand your answer. For general closed convex set $P$, my question is wrong. How about if $P$ is a positive cone? I think I ask it again on another question, since your answer is good enough for a specific question.

Comment: @0706 Im not sure what positive cone is in this context. But similar approach is likely to work. If I were you I'd rather focus on additional assumptions on $r$. Note that the Tietze theorem doesn't tell us anything about $r$ except that it exists and is continuous.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your example can be modified for a positive cone. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

(2) is true.

Note that (2) only makes sense if $r$ is linear. In that case $P$ must be a closed linear subspace of $X$ (since the image of a linear map is always a linear subspace).

Now (2) is due to the fact the the composition $T \circ L$ is compact if $L$ is linear and continuous and $T$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right. If $r$ is a continuous linear map, then $r$ is bounded. However, in general, retraction map is not linear. I believe that (2) should be true for retraction maps, since fixed point index is induced by the fact and Leray-Schauder degree.

Comment: Okay, but if you allow a general retraction $r$, then $T \circ r$ is just a map and not a (compact) operator. However, it may have the property that the image of a bounded set is relatively compact. By the way, this is why I wrote that (2) only makes sense if $r$ is linear. Perhaps you should edit your question.

Comment: I’ve edited my question. Sorry for my unclear question.